# How do you use a variable with FontAwesome unicode as a placeholder in reacstrap 4 Input placeholder

Tags: reactjs, jsx, reactstrap, font-awesome-4

I am currently using a reactstrap 4 Input component and everything looks great when I set the placeholder to a static string (Note: The FontAwesome font is loaded way higher in the app, and as you can see it works fine):

```
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';
```

```
<Input
  style={{ fontFamily: 'FontAwesome, sans-serif' }}
  placeholder="&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search by Album Title or ID"
/>
```

[image: Placeholder shows FontAwesome correctly]

---

However, I now need to make the placeholder text dynamic and pass it in as a prop. When I do this, everything breaks, and instead of showing the FontAwesome icon, it shows the raw unicode.

```
<Input
  style={{ fontFamily: 'FontAwesome, sans-serif' }}
  placeholder={props.placeholderText}
/>
```

```
AlbumsFilter.defaultProps = {
  placeholderText: "&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search by Album Title or ID"
};
```

[image: No Icon, just raw unicode when I use a variable]

---

Here is a list of placeholder props I've tried passing, and *none* of them work:

```
placeholder={props.placeholderText}
placeholder={String(props.placeholderText)}
placeholder={`${props.placeholderText}`}
placeholder={props.placeholderText.toString()}
placeholder={"&#xf002;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + props.placeholderText}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and use the npm library `html-entities`:

using:

`npm i html-entities`

then:

`import { decode } from 'html-entities'`;

and

`placeholder={decode(props.placeholderText)}`